# Why is the mathematica code converges slower than expected?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods, ode

I was writing the mathematica code in order to calculate the numerical solution of ODE by Runge–Kutta Method of order four (RK4), which has the formula:

[image]

I want to calculate y(1) of the ODE:

[image]

The mathematica that I wrote is

```js
RungeKnutta[f_, ya_, a_, b_, h_] := If[
   a >= b,
   {ya},
   Block[{
     s1 = f[a, ya],
     s2 = f[a + h/2, ya + h/2 s1],
     s3 = f[a + h/2, ya + h/2 s2],
     s4 = f[a + h, ya + h s3],
     nextY = ya + h/6 (s1 + 2 s2 + 2 s3 + s4)
     }, Prepend[RungeKnutta[f, nextY, a + h, b, h], ya]]];

f[t_, y_] := t y;

RungeKnutta[f, 1, 0, 1, 0.25] 
// output: {1, 1.03174, 1.06349, 1.16136, 1.3348}
```

The (expected) equivalent python code:

```py
def rk4(f, ya, a, b, h):
    if a >= b:
        return [ya]
    else:
        s1 = f(a, ya)
        s2 = f(a + h/2, ya + h/2 * s1)
        s3 = f(a + h/2, ya + h/2 * s2)
        s4 = f(a + h, ya + h*s3)
        nextY = ya + h/6 * (s1 + 2*s2 + 2*s3 + s4)
        return [ya] + rk4(f, nextY, a + h, b, h)


print(rk4(lambda t, y: t * y, 1, 0, 1, 0.25))
# output: [1, 1.0317433675130208, 1.1331479769190385, 1.324782173512337, 1.64870973607629]
```

What is the problem in my mathematica code that leads to the diverget result with the python code?

Comment: Do you really need to write this yourself? See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html

Comment: The python code is correct, if compared with the exact solution `exp(t^2/2)`. You should perhaps ask in the Mathematica SE forum if there is some issue with scoping or deferred evaluation or whatever.

Comment: In a fresh MMA 13.1 notebook I paste `f[t_,y_]:=t*y; rk4[f_,ya_,a_,b_,h_]:=If[a>=b,ya, s1=f[a,ya];s2=f[a+h/2,ya+h/2*s1];s3=f[a+h/2,ya+h/2*s2];s4=f[a+h,ya+h*s3];nextY=ya+h/6*(s1+2*s2+2*s3+s4);{ya,rk4[f,nextY,a+h,b,h]}]; Flatten[rk4[f,1,0,1,0.25]]` and it responds with `{1,1.03174,1.13315,1.32478,1.64871}`

Comment: If I then `Abort[]` and then paste your MMA code unchanged then the output is `{1,1.32393,1.3615,1.48692,1.70898}` which doesn't match either of your outputs. If I `Abort` and then change your `Block` to `Module` then the output is `{1,1.32393,1.64786,1.97178,2.29571}` which matches none of these.

Comment: The question mentions ty+t³, but you implement ty. Why is that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That was my incaution, corrected. Thanks for pointing it out.